# Database relation and inserting a row

Tags: mysql, insert

I am building a cash register for my work place. I am having a trouble with Mysql.

I have db with three tables.

**orders** (where it stores : list_id, order_id (FK from order_line table),Id (FK for product id from product table), qty, total).

**order_line** (Where it stores : order_id, order_date, order_time )

**products** (id,product_name,product_desc,price)

What i want to do is to add the order in database. Insert into order_line a date and time and order_id(auto increment)
Also insert the items into orders table where it can retrieve order_id from order_line table so i can have same order_num for each item in orders table.

so far, this is what i tried;

```
INSERT INTO order_line 
VALUES('','04/25/2015','11.52.06');
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES ('','orders_ibfk_2','orders_ibfk_1','2',30.00);
```

and recieved an error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shoelacestore`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`))

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Does the products table have a row with an ID of 'orders_ibfk_1'? The error suggests that it doesn't

Comment: it does not; however when i try the id number 7, it returns the same error. Is my insert logic right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your id column data types are not integer. Make it integer if it is ok. 
when you execute following query

```
INSERT INTO order_line 
VALUES(0,'04/25/2015','11.52.06');
```

You will get a value for `order_id`. Just assume it is 344

And assume in your `products table` you have a product with `id` 98

Then you can use follwing query to insert into

```
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES (0,344,98,'2',30.00);
```

i assume all ids are integers

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the solution.

```
INSERT INTO T1 (col1,col2) VALUES (val1,val2); 
SET @last_id_in_T1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO T2 (col1,col2) VALUES (@last_id_in_T1,val2);
```

so basicly, T1 is the table for order_line which creates an auto increment order_id. SET @last_id_in_T1 = LAST_INSERT_ID(); copies the last order_id and inputs into orders table as i wished.

I hope this will help others as well.